# cURL and website login

Tags: shell, curl

I am trying to use cURL to login to the site FictFact (http://www.fictfact.com).  I have looked at previous StackOverflow posts about the general topic and have tried many different solutions, but haven't hit on the proper one.

```
curl --data "UserName=name&Password=pass&RememberMe=false" http://www.fictfact.com/account/logon
```

This returns an Object Moved message.

```
curl --form "UserName=name&Password=pass&RememberMe=false&submit=Login" http://www.fictfact.com/account/logon
```

This returns the HTML of the login form page.  I tried this without the "submit" and also with a -X POST.

Lastly, I have tried a few variations of sending cookies:
    curl -c cookies.txt http://www.fictfact.com/account/logon
This creates the cookies.txt file and then I use this call to use it:
    curl -b cookies.txt --form "UserName=name&Password=pass&RememberMe=false&submit=Login" --dump-header headers http://www.fictfact.com/account/logon

This still only returns the login form...not the post-authenticated page.

Is this a site-specific problem or is there something general I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Creating a test account on fictfact.com for us to run tests would help. Or else please post the name/password you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Martin Konecny](https://superuser.com/a/396659) answer I got login working:

```
$ curl --data "UserName=plebian&Password=password&RememberMe=false" http://www.fictfact.com/account/logon --dump-header headers 
$ curl -L -b headers http://www.fictfact.com/Account/LogOn 

[..]
 <div class="navitems">
                Welcome <strong>plebian</strong>!
    [ <a href="/account/logoff">Log Off</a> ]
[..]
```

Comment: Removing previous comment.  Thanks for your help!